# GAS error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null (line 4, file "Code2")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The GAS code bellow outputs an error while running the function `fromPS`: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null (line 4, file "Code2")`

I cannot see what is wrong in this code. I have tried to use the property `getSheetByName` instead of `getSheets`, but both the error still the same.

What do you see that I do not?

Thank you!

code:

```
function toSpreadsheet(text2write)
  { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //getSheetByName("HIL_APP_Log");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++)
  {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 8, 1).setValue(text2write)
  }
  return "myreturn"
}

function fromPS() //fromPS(params)
{
  params = "fromGAS"
  Logger.log(params) 
  var rtn = toSpreadsheet(params)
  return rtn
}
```

Comment: Code is solid. I ran it on my end and it works fine. Try it in another google sheet and see if it works. If it doesn't, restart the computer and try again.

Comment: Is your script bound to a sheet correctly? Did you access it through Tools > Script Editor? Could you share what your spreadsheet looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code worked fine before. For an unknown reason, `getActiveSpreadsheet()` was not finding any active spreadsheet, then it was returning `null`.

To fix that I had to create another Script project. Now the same code runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Cannot read property 'getLastRow' means that `sheet.getLastRow()` does not exist

The reason is `sheet` is defined wrongly.

For example if you specify `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];`

while your spreadsheet has less than 2 sheets or

`var sheet = ss.getSheets().getSheetByName("WRONG NAME");`,

which commonly occurs if you do not respect case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I had similar error. I changed

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Name of spreadsheet");
```

for

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

And now works !