# Inventory update function in JS not working (from a Google forms response sheet, updating separate file sheet)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, inventory

The cells are correct. I’m trying to update stock count, so when someone submits a response on Google Sheet Merch sales (Responses), the data from a column in that row in the sheet is taken and then can be subtracted from a number in a cell in another sheet, called updated stock count. So customers can check the updated stock count sheet before their next purchase so they will know if what they want is in stock or not.

```
function updateStockCountForL() {
  var formSheetName = "Merch sales (Responses)";
  var responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(formSheetName);
  
  var stockSheetName = "updated stock count";
  var stockSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(stockSheetName);
  
  var lastResponseRow = responseSheet.getLastRow();
  var columnToCheck = "H"; // Change this to the appropriate column letter
  
  var newCellValue = responseSheet.getRange(lastResponseRow, columnToCheck).getValue();
  var stockCellAddress = "G3"; // Change this to the cell address containing the stock count
  
  var stockCell = stockSheet.getRange(stockCellAddress);
  var currentStockCount = stockCell.getValue();
  
  var updatedStockCount = currentStockCount - newCellValue;
  stockCell.setValue(updatedStockCount);
}
```

As I haven't learnt JavaScript before but Google apps script is only JS or CSS, I used ChatGPT to generate this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')
```

I don't understand what this means.

Comment: The best way to be heard here is to ask a high-quality question. You can do this by simply following the `How to ask` guidelines. Formatting your code, adding snippets or sandboxes is what will attract people to answer your question. This way, people have to edit, format and then analyze your question. Please format your code properly.

Comment: `as i haven't learnt js before` This is unfortunate. I recommend you start by reading the [Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and take it from there as your needs dictate.

Comment: It probably means that there is no such sheet as `Merch sales (Responses)`. You could do some trouble shooting to clarify whether that is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GAS error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null (line 4, file "Code2")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782798/gas-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-getlastrow-of-null-line-4-file-c)